# Java serialization of EJB entity not serializing one member of ManyToMany set - but only sometimes

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, ejb

For a server-to-server sync process, I am serializing EJB entity objects across the network. The servers are JBoss 5, using Hibernate for persistence. In this development scenario, my remote server is running on Ubuntu Linux with sun-java6-jdk 1.6.0_24-b07, while my development machine is running OS X with Java 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326.

One of my classes is User, who can belong to one or more Groups. The problem I'm having is that, for a specific User, not all of the associated Group objects are coming through the serialization: that user is assigned to two groups, but only one is coming through. Other users are coming through fine, be they assigned either to two groups (analog to the affected user) or only to the missing group or the other group.

User is the "owner" of the ManyToMany relation, and is related to Group as follows.

**User**

```java
public class User implements Serializable, Cloneable, DynamicEntity, Identifiable, Comparable<User> {
    // Other stuff omitted...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "tbl_user_group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
}
```

**Group**

```java
public class Group implements Serializable, Identifiable, Comparable<Group> {
    // Other stuff omitted...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<User> users = new TreeSet<User>();
}
```

On the remote server side, I have a service that collects the objects and returns them as a `List<?>[]`. Here is the service method that is called by clients.

```java
public List<?>[] getSyncData() {
    final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<?>[] data = null;
    try {
        data = getLocalData(em, toSlaveServices);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return data;
}
```

In the getLocalData method I log which objects are being processed.

```
 User masteruser: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
 User admin: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62], Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 User allgroups: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62], Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 User slave62: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 User d8a0f514-0930-41fb-8028-5db9e8a2824c: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 User px: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 Sending [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62], Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
```

I have included all users and groups for context: the one I'm interested in is User **allgroups** on the third line. As you can see, allgroups belongs to two groups, master62 and slave62.

On the client side, I also log which objects I receive back from the server.

```
 User masteruser: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
 User admin: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62], Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
 User allgroups: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
 User slave62: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 User d8a0f514-0930-41fb-8028-5db9e8a2824c: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 User px: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
 Received [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62], Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
```

As you can see, everything comes through as expected, *except* the allgroups user, who comes through with membership in only one group.

To see if I could track down what was going on, I decided to manually try serialization into files of the both the affected user object alone, and then the whole List array. Here's the modified `getSyncData` method:

```java
public List<?>[] getSyncData() {
    final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<?>[] data = null;
    try {
        data = getLocalData(em, toSlaveServices);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (List<?> datum : data) {
        fgLogger.debug("Sending " + datum);
        if (datum != null && datum.size() > 0 && datum.get(0).getClass() == User.class) {
            for (User user : ((List<User>) datum)) {
                fgLogger.debug("User " + user.getUser_id() + ": " + user.getGroups());

                if ("allgroups".equals(user.getUser_id())) {
                    try {
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/user-" + time + ".ser"));
                        oos.writeObject(user);
                        oos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/ssi-" + time + ".ser"));
        oos.writeObject(data);
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

I then copied the two serialization files from the remote server to my client, and tried reading them in using a simple Groovy script (i.e. not from within JBoss), first the user-xxx.ser file, and then the ssi-xxx.ser file.

```
*** USER ***
User allgroups: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62], Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
*** SSI ***
User masteruser: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
User admin: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62], Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
User allgroups: [Group [899d07bf-28f9-437a-8811-6d53b8f2df5d, master62]]
User slave62: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
User d8a0f514-0930-41fb-8028-5db9e8a2824c: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
User px: [Group [0d293aa6-c5af-4a03-a8ce-edea9b05acb7, slave62]]
```

The results under the SSI bit mirror my experience serializing across the net. The serialized user alone, however, contains both groups, as I want! These two serialization files were generated in the same method, using the same raw data - though the user was obviously nested within the other data structure.

How can the results for the *allgroups* user be different?? I'm baffled, and would be very grateful for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested:

I haven't found an answer to the question. I suspect it has something to do with the way the linked Group objects are stored in a Hibernate `PersistentSet` (although `PersistentSet` and the `HashSet` backing it are both serializable). I have given up on debugging - time is money.

I worked around the problem by adding an additional field to my User entity, `Set<String> groupIds`. I fill up this set in `User.writeObject`, which is called when User is serialized. On the receiving side, I clear out the groups set, and then manually search for the groups based on the IDs stored in the groupIds field. I then add the groups to the user's group set. It's cumbersome, and it requires that I have first synchronized the groups in order to be able to reassign them - but it works.